# How do I make formulas effective only starting from tomorrow in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I made a Google Sheet for insulin-dependent diabetics, to calculate insulin units based on their meal content and glucose reading inputs. Each day has its own block of cells for the patient. When I edit the governing formulas in another sheet called 'factors', how do I make them effective starting from tomorrow, leaving previously calculated cells unchanged, to get back to as a history?

Here is the formula I'm using in a C5 calculating cell:

```
=if(C4="","",(C4-factors!C$7)/factors!C$5+C3/factors!C$3)
```

And [Here is an example of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zs6UB6xce7QeEm2MD2FGnNCllMGuTe4xk0dm4-wPHy8/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Welcome. You need to take dates into account. I don't see any in your sheet. It would really help if your sheet was in english. Also. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Thanks. There is a link to a test sheet in my question. Please elaborate on what do you mean by taking dates into account. I have changed some key contents into English as you suggested.